# NVD3: Force Bar + Line Chart to use same axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Does anyone have a simple way to force both a line and bar chart to use the same Y axis in an NVD3 chart?  When starting with the following, they take Y1 and Y2.

http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html

If left to my own devices, I would suspect I should adapt linePlusBarChart.js, but it'll take some fumbling around as I learn the syntax / methods.  Any shortcuts are welcome.

Comment: You could force both axes to have the same domain, but if you want just one you'll have to modify the source.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm currently in the same boat. Thanks!

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, how would I force both axes to have same domain?

Comment: @tmthyjames You may be able to use `.forceX(low,high)` and `forceY()` depending on the type of chart.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using the wrong model. A better starting point is this:
http://www.labtsmith.com/nvd3/examples/multiChart.html